# jQuery deferred promises does not seem to work for opening new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to achieve the following, with the work flow in sequence:
1. Retrieve a URL which contains a redirect URI/URL if successful.
2. Open new window with retrieved URL, which redirects basically back to the same page but now, the URL has 'code=randomCode' appended to the back of the URL.
3. Parse out the randomCode to use as input for something else.

Problem:
At this moment, I'm using jQuery promises to first $.get(number 1), .then(do number 2), .then(do number 3).

The issue is that this whole function only appears to work after one failure. i.e every single time I refresh, the first time the new window will open, but the other parts will not succeed, i.e the randomCode will not be succcessfully parsed out because during that stage, somehow jQuery cannot detect the opened window, even though it should because it's using .then.

However, after the first failure, once the window is opened, every subsequent attempt succeeds at retrieving everything correctly.

What is going on? Can someone help? My code sample is below:

```
var retrievedURL;
var desiredString;
function getURL() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(firstURL) // assume valid URL
                .then(function(response) {
                    $('#url').html('Click this');
                    $('#url-link').attr("href",response.url);
                    retrievedURL = response.url;
                })
                .then(function() {
                    newWindow = window.open(retrievedURL ,'test');
                })
                .then(function() {
                    desiredString = newWindow.location.search.substr(6);
                })


    })
}
```

So that's the gist of the function. I of course then go on to do something with desiredString, but somehow, every single time, the first run through, desiredString is null.

Comment: remove the getURL function. this is preventing your code from being bound to document.ready

Comment: tried it, then it runs in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new window does a redirect then you aren't accounting for the time for it to do such. You need a load event listener on new window and then get the url

The last `then()` is not going to wait for that new window to load it will get called almost instantly. You would need to return a promise from the second `then()` to have the last `then()` fire after that promise was resolved

Try

```
 $.get(firstURL) // assume valid URL
            .then(function(response) {
                $('#url').html('Click this');
                $('#url-link').attr("href",response.url);
                retrievedURL = response.url;
            })
            .then(function() {
                newWindow = window.open(retrievedURL ,'test');
                // listen for window to load
                newWindow.onload = function(){
                   desiredString = newWindow.location.search.substr(6);
                   // do something with desiredString
                }
            })
```

Comment: YESSSSS IT WORKS I LOVE YOU. dude, seriously i spent days on this and you just solved it!

Answer (score 0):

remove the getURL function. this is preventing your code from being bound to document.ready
try this:

```
var retrievedURL;
var desiredString;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(firstURL) // assume valid URL
    .then(function(response) {
        $('#url').html('Click this');
        $('#url-link').attr("href",response.url);
        retrievedURL = response.url; }) 
    .then(function() { 
        newWindow = window.open(retrievedURL ,'test');
    }) 
    .then(function() { 
        desiredString = newWindow.location.search.substr(6); 
    })
});
```

Comment: in what way? what part is calling itsself?

Comment: erm, the new window that opens just keeps refreshing with a new retrieved code while the original window... well nothing happens there. i'm not exactly sure what is going on, but the newly opened window keeps refreshing and retrieving a new code.

Comment: i think your code auto runs once upon document is ready, but the issue is because the new window is also basically the same page with the same code, except with a new parameter added to the URL string, so once it's ready it then runs the same code again, and again, and again...